# How to increase the height and Width of Primefaces Checkbox

Tags: css, primefaces, stylesheet

I am using Primefaces version 5.2 . I need to increase the height nd width of check box , i tried two possible css and tried to override but i couldnt find any changes. As i am new to Styling can some one tell me whats the rightway to do it

CSS example 1

```
.ui-chkbox-icon.ui-icon {
    width: 32px;
    width:32px;

.ui-chkbox-blank.ui-icon {
    width: 32px;
    width:32px;
    overflow: visible;
}
.ui-chkbox-check.ui-icon {
    width: 32px;
    width:32px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

CSS example 2

```
.ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-box {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}

.ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-icon {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}

.ui-chkbox  .ui-chkbox-label {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}
.ui-chkbox  .ui-chkbox-blank{
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}
ui-chkbox  .ui-chkbox-check {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}
```

Result after using

```
body .ui-chkbox, body .ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-box {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}

.ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-label {
    line-height: 32px;
```

}

[image]

Comment: Can you post also the XHTML of these checkboxes as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Answer (score 1):

```
body .ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-box {

    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;

}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

```css
body .ui-chkbox, body .ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-box {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}
body .ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-label {
    line-height: 32px;
}
```

Try this

Comment: Your checkbox looks differently, is it some kind of custom theme? When I applied my styles, I've been looking for this example [primefaces boolean checkbox](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/booleanCheckbox.xhtml)